# The heap memory keeps on increasing on managed servers even though the load test has ended, what could be the reason?

Tags: performance, load-testing, memory-leaks

We are having a strange observation while performance testing our web application which is, even after the load test ends, the heap keeps on increasing, what could be the issue? The environment for PT is seperate and hence it is assumed that no one is using that environment except for when we run the load test scripts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about server monitoring and not testing. Although this occurs during a load-test I think this question is better asked on http://serverfault.com/ Maybe also add a bit more context, as most voted to close this question is unclear.